# Does deleting a Facebook posting also delete the comments?

Tags: facebook

If I delete someone's post on my Facebook page does it delete the comments on that post too?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it deletes all comments, likes and shares of that post. I answered and tested this before in 2012, I'm sure it still applies now

I posted a status update to a test user Betty

[image: Betty]

Then had three other test users share it one after the other

[image: All the friends share it]

So Tom shared it > Joe shared what Tom shared > Patricia shared what Joe shared

Then for completeness I had Betty share it again

[image: Betty shares again]

On delete, all posts are gone from all test users, including the re-share Betty made.

As long as the user shares via the action link all subsequent shares will be deleted if the original is deleted.

But if the user manually copies it or saves a photo then re-uploads then no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I know this because it ruined one of my family relationships were harmed.

By deleting the post, you are deleting the comments attached to it. Therefor, if the thing the comments are tied to are gone, so are the comments (or at least not visible)

Answer (score -1):

Yah it does, unless the post was in the form of a share to your page.

Comment: Do you have any references for this? Thx